# Rails -> Best Way to turn the result of a database query into a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that allows the user to pick the name of their spouse from a members model using options_for_select.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label "Spouse:", :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
  <%= select_tag 'spouse', 
      options_for_select(
        @members.where("last_name = ?", @member.last_name)
          .collect{ |u| [ u.first_name + " " + u.last_name ] }, 
        @member.spouse
      ),
      :class => "col-sm-5", :style=>"padding:10px;",
      :prompt => 'None'
  %>
</div>
```

I then take the user's answer and store the spouse's last and first name in database.

In the View I use the following to display the answer:

```
Spouse:<%= @member.spouse %>
```

I would like to add link_to to this snippet to allow users to review the profile of the spouse.

I believe that the problem is that I'm not storing the spouse's id number which prevents linked_to from working within the show view.

How do I get the spouses' member id from the options_select command in the _form.html.erb? And, how do I set-up the link_to in the Show view?

My controller code is below:

```
def show
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])

  @show_courses = @member.courses
  @show_ministry = @member.ministries

  @birthday = @member.birthday
  @show_kids = @member.kids
  @show_strengths = member.strengths
  @show_spouse = @member.spouse
  @show_gender = @member.gender
end

def update
  params[:member][:course_ids] ||= []
  params[:member][:ministry_ids] ||= []
  params[:member][:kid_ids] ||= []
  params[:member][:strength_ids] ||= []
  params[:spouse]

  Member.update(@member, :spouse => params[:spouse])
  Member.update(@member, :gender => params[:gender])
  Member.update(@member, :strength_all => params[:strength_ids])

  @member = Member.find(params[:id])
  @members = Member.all
  @all_courses = @member.courses
```

UPDATE: Here is my Member Model Code:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
              validates :birthday, length: { maximum: 30 }, allow_nil: true

              validates :spouse, presence: true, allow_blank: true
              validates :email, presence: true, on: :create
              scope :spouse_names, -> { :spouse.order(last_name: :asc) } 

            def publish_month
              created_at.strftime("%B %Y")
            end
                # Export List
                def self.to_csv(options = {})
                  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
                    csv << column_names
                    all.each do |member|
                      csv << member.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
                    end
                  end
                end

                # Import List
                def self.import(file)
                  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
                  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
                  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
                    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
                    member = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
                    parameter = ActionController::Parameters.new(row.to_hash)
                    member.update(parameter.permit(:id, :birthday, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :spouse, :strength_ids, :gender, :password))
                    member.save!
                    end
                end

                def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
                  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
                  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, csv_options: {encoding: "iso-8859-1:utf-8"})
                  when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
                  when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
                  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
                  end
                end

                has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
                has_and_belongs_to_many :ministries
                has_and_belongs_to_many :kids
                has_and_belongs_to_many :strengths

                has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { mini: "50x50", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, 
                    :default_url => "default_avatar"

                validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] 

                def first_and_last
                    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
                end

            end
```

Comment: does the spouse gets added? and what is `spouse` is it a simple attribute or a relation?

Comment: modify your collect method to.. `.collect{ |u| [ u.first_name + " " + u.last_name , u.id ] }` now the value passed to server will be u.id instead of the lastname

Comment: I added my Member model.  I'm sure that this isn't the optimal way to do this.  Still getting up the RoR learning curve

Comment: I get this error now: 
Couldn't find Member with 'id'=
Do I need to change the collection_tag in the _form.html.erb to make sure an id number is sent to the controller Update method?

Comment: yup you need to find change it in the form field

Comment: But do have a look at the solution by Minato below... it's much easier when you define the relationship to itself in the form of the has_one :spouse relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... You might've to redesign your user model and view profile a bit..

This is one way to do it... I suppose There might be some others that I am not aware of ATM ok so lets start..

## Note: I am assuming you are using rails 4.2.. steps are a bit different on other versions..

## Note: I would like to change your code minimally..

1. delete your `spouse` attribute and have a `has_one` and `belongs_to` relation in your `Member` model.

   Generate this migration from shell

   ```
   rails g migration AddSpouseToMembers spouse:references
   ```

   and verify these lines

   ```
   add_reference :members, :spouse
   add_foreign_key :spouse, :members, column: :spouse_id
   ```

   add this line before those two.

   ```
   remove_column :members, :spouse
   ```

   and run the migrations

   You can add the said `relation`  simply by adding these to your `Member` model.

   ```
    has_one :spouse, class_name: "Member", foreign_key: :spouse_id
    belongs_to :spouse, class_name: "Member", foreign_key: :spouse_id
   ```
2. Change the line where you assign spouse in your controller code to

   ```
    Member.update(@member, :spouse => Member.find(params[:spouse]))
   ```
3. Change your view to

   ```
    Spouse:<%= link_to @member.spouse.first_name, @member.spouse if @member.spouse.present? %>
   ```

## Note: And a very important one.. I don't know your system so use some VCS.. this might not work completely for you.

Hope it helps

Comment: Is the update to the related recod infered in Rails, or should TS also create a callback to update the related record as well? Just wondering...

Comment: @bo-oz I didn't quite understand your question.. `TS`? what is that... `Member.update()` takes 2 `parameters` `id`,`values` and rails is smart enough to call `id` on `@member` and updates the record with that `id` with the values provided in `values` so when updating I am linking the user profile selected as `spouse` by the current member. Well there may be a lot of errors w.r.t the project in focus. but O.P should get the idea..

Comment: TS was my abbreviation for O.P :), not really used to the SO conventions.

Comment: @bo-oz by callback if you mean pass a block like `Member.update(id,values) { |m| puts m }` yes you can do that and `m` will be the updated record if the `query` executed/committed successfully..

Comment: I understand, but I was wondering if Rails also automatically updates the related record so that the spouse also has the same relationship back to the original spouse..

Comment: I feel we are on the right track here. I made your changes and I'm getting 
undefined method `find' for Members:Module

Is thus because we are referencing Members in the controller instead of 
Member?  I tried changing this to Member but this seemed to cause a recursive loop.

Comment: then I'll try to see if I can fix that.. :)

Comment: @Stan yeah you are right.. I almost always make that typo of pluralizing the model class name  ..*facepalm* `Member.find(params[:spouse])` should do the trick..

Comment: Thanks @Minato, I'm getting a Could not log "sql.active_record" event. SystemStackError: stack level too deep error now.  But I upvoted your original answer because it put me on the right track.

Comment: you can also do `@member.spouse = Member.find(params[:spouse])` but I guess the former should work too

Comment: @Stan you'll have to have a  check on whether a person is setting himself as his spouse..

Comment: @Stan I mean one shouldn't marry himself... and can you expose the complete form in you erb? I think.. if spouse is inside the form .. you can't use `params[:spouse]` you have to do `params[:formname][:member]` or `params[:formname].permit(:spouse)`

Answer (score 0):

You really need to refactor those Controller methods, each call to @member.xxxx is triggering a seperate query, so your show method now consist of about 5 queries (some or attributes so it seems)! All the informaiton you are setting is already part of @member. So the Rails way of writing that show method would be to do something like:

```
def show
  @member = Member.find(params[:id]).includes(:spouse, :courses, :ministries, :kids) #define all related models
end
```

In your views you can just call the parts you want to show, preferably by rendering partials like this:

```
  render @member.courses
```

Which will call the `partial courses/_course.html.erb`

Same goes for your update, calling update 3 times, creates 3 seperate UPDATE queries (have a look at your server in terminal to confirm). Also, Rails is smart enough to save all related model data directly. You also should use Rails 4 strong parameters to access form submitted data:

```
def update
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])
  @member.update(member_params)
end

  private

  def member_params
    params.require(:member).permit(:birthday, :gender, course_ids: [], ministry_ids: [], kid_ids: []) # complete this for your specific case, add all the options you would like the form to save
  end
```

Comment: Reading the answer by @minato made me realize that you probably need to confirm your relationship setup, could you post the Member model?

Comment: Your demonstration of using `includes` is good and correct/better. But you do realize that that will also run 5 separate queries, right? Calling `includes` still runs a separate query for each included model (though lazily, when the included models are used elsewhere in the controller or view).

Comment: You're right, thanks for the feedback! But includes does save you queries right?

Comment: Are you asking if it caches the query results for the remainder of the request? If so, yes. But I believe that it will do that in either case.